# Solving the following relation in triangle

Tags: euclidean-geometry

If a line through the centroid $G$ of a triangle ABC meets $AB$ in $M$ and $AC$ on $N$ then prove that $AN. MB+AM. NC=AM. AN$ both in magnitude as well as sign

I tired dividing the equation by $AM. AN$ 
Thus resultant became $\frac{MB}{AM}+\frac{NC}{AN}=1$ and now I tried to do some construction but couldn't figure out the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Draw perpendicular lines to line $MN$ through $A$, $B$, $C$, and the midpoint $D$ of $BC$. Turn the ratios you got into ratios of the length of the perpendicular segments.

Comment: Could you please elaborate

Comment: You want to prove that the distance from $A$ to line $MN$ is equal to the total distances from $B$ and $C$ to line $MN$. Do you see it?

Comment: I got this i used the idea that you gave of drawing perpendiculars and then I used similarities but how can I further prove that the distance from A to MN is equal to the sum of the distances from B to MN and from C to MN please help.  Thanks

Comment: How about the perpendicular from $G$? How does it relate to the other perpendiculars?

Comment: I ain't getting it please present give a solution

Comment: Using similarity, you should be able to show the distance from $A$ is twice the distance from $G$.

Comment: Yeh I got that and then

Comment: Don't know how to do so

Comment: Now use the fact that $D$ is the midpoint of $BC$ to show that the distance from $D$ is half of the total distance from $B$ and $C$.

Comment: Please explain and give a full solution please please

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be the intersection of the lines $MN$ and $BC$. Here is a picture:

[image: mse 882522]

Apply the theorem of [Menelaus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menelaus%27s_theorem) for the triangles $\Delta ABD$,  $\Delta ADC$ to get (using sign conventions for proportions of two segments on the same line):

$$
\begin{aligned}
1 &= 
\frac{MB}{MA}\cdot \underbrace{\frac{GA}{GD}}_{=-2}\cdot \frac{XD}{XB}\ ,
\\ 
1 &= 
\frac{NC}{NA}\cdot \underbrace{\frac{GA}{GD}}_{=-2}\cdot \frac{XD}{XC}\ ,
\qquad\text{ and from here}
\\[3mm]
\frac{MB}{MA} + \frac{NC}{NA}
&=-\frac 12\left( \frac{XB}{XD} + \frac{XC}{XD}\right)
= -\frac 12\cdot\frac{XB+XC}{XD}= -\frac 12\cdot\frac{2XD}{XD}
=\boxed{\ -1\ }\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
$\square$

---

*Note:* By sign convention we have
$\displaystyle
\frac{MB}{MA} = -\frac{MB}{AM}$, and
$\displaystyle
\frac{NC}{NA} = -\frac{NB}{AN}$, making the sign a plus one for the sum in the question.